# two connected relationships in a realm object

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm rather new to realm and I'm trying to figure out the right design for the interaction between my REST API and storing into realm objects. so far I have an `Animal` object looking like below:

```
class Animal: Object, Mappable {
    dynamic var id = ""
    dynamic var userId = ""
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var gender = ""
    dynamic var breed: Breed?
    dynamic var type: Type?

    //extra
    var mainPhotoIndex = 0


    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }


    required convenience init?(map: Map) {
        self.init()
    }

}
```

However the problem is that I'm not sure how I can handle the `Type` and `Breed` relationship since type consist of a list of all the breeds, which mean in order to retrieve an animal with the corresponding breed name and type name I would have to populate these two properties on server side, which would make the JSON objects huge when I on the animal object only need to retrieve the two names of the `Type` and `Breed`. The other approach I found was to just save the `String` ObjectId and then filter by that id in the realm database, but not sure that this is best practice. So what do I need to pass on the server side here and how should I design my animal realm object?

**Type**

```
class Type: Object, Mappable {
    dynamic var id = ""
    dynamic var name = ""
    var breeds = List<Breed>()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }

    required convenience init?(map: Map) {
        self.init()
    }

}
```

**Breed**

```
class Breed: Object, Mappable {
    dynamic var id = ""
    dynamic var name = ""

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }

    required convenience init?(map: Map) {
        self.init()
    }

}
```

Comment: Your classes definition is correct. To solve a problem of huge JSON you could just provide an ID's to Type and Breed, when you posting / retrieving it to/from server.
All Types and Breeds are already persisted in local database from your/types endpoint, so you can retrieve them by ID, when creating a particular animal and assign them as a property of your animal.

Comment: I thought about that was just not sure that saving id's as string was good practice in realm

Comment: Why saving as strings then? Integer could be the right choise

Comment: i'm using `mongoDB` where ObjectId seem to be a string.

Comment: Convert it into string, while parsing JSON on the server side could be the option

Answer (score 0):

You're completely correct. Your schema is set up in the right way, but you're correct in that mapping `Animal` from a JSON string would require having to include everything from `Type` and `Breed` as well. But it should be possible to compromise on this.

It sounds like `Type` and `Breed` are two sets of completely static data that are pretty much independent of `Animal`. They also have primary keys. That all being the case, I would recommend downloading all of the contents of `Breed` and `Type` that you require and save that locally to Realm the first time you need to.

After that, whenever you request an `Animal`, the contents of the JSON string instead of including the contents of the `Breed` and `Type` objects can instead simply include the primary keys of the necessary objects. Then, when performing the mapping operation in ObjectMapper, you can manually take those two keys, query Realm for the appropriate objects, and then link them up entirely locally on your disk.